# How come Sherlock still remembers how to play the violin?

Tags: plot-explanation, sherlock

In *Sherlock* *S04E03*, when Sherlock meets Eurus in her cell, Eurus asks Sherlock to play the violin and professes that she taught Sherlock how to play the violin.

> EURUS: You play, don’t you?
>
> SHERLOCK: How did you know?
>
> EURUS: **How did I know? I taught you, don’t you remember?** How can you not remember that?
>
> SHERLOCK: Eurus, I don’t remember you at all.
>
> EURUS: Interesting. Mycroft told me you’d rewritten your memories; he didn’t tell me you’d written me out completely.
>
> Source: http://arianedevere.livejournal.com

Sherlock had completely rewritten any memories associated with Eurus, made his best friend into a dog *(somehow reminds me of the S02E02, Hounds of Baskerville episode)*.

Returning back to the question, if Sherlock had blocked every bond with Eurus, how come he still remembers how to play the violin; despite the fact that it was Eurus who taught him to play the violin, in the first place.

Comment: Students of a musical instrument might have a number of teachers, each of which teach more advanced (or at least different) concepts than the last. It could be that Sherlock 'transferred' his memories of the first teacher, onto the second.

Comment: If I met my driving instructor today I doubt I would recognise him, so many years have passed by, but I still know how to drive a car. In this case, it sounds as if Sherlock has deliberately chosen to erase her, not his violin playing skills, from his mind,

Comment: @mari but you remember that your driving instructor taught you.  Sherlock is a little more complex.

Comment: @cde Sherlock says *“I don’t remember **you** at all”*, he doesn't say nobody taught him how to play the violin. Big difference :)

Comment: Do YOU remember the person who taught you A, B, C? I certainly don't. Then how can I even write this comment??

Comment: I know a guy who had to be taught how to eat, walk, and talk after a terrible car accident but he somehow remembered how to play hundreds of songs on the guitar even though he couldn't remember the names of any of the songs.

Comment: @todd that sounds like motor skills part of the brain was damaged. Not a equivalent situation.

Comment: @cde I don't know the medical stuff, but he forgot almost everything about his life. He couldn't remember that he was dating this woman. He didn't remember people in his life like his friends and coworkers. When he was reminded of things he could usually remember them better than someone learning for the first time.

Comment: If this is even considered to be a flaw, it is way smaller than the other plot flaws in that strange episode. I got the impression that the makers of Sherlock just got tired and wanted to put an end to all the suffering.

Answer (score 22):

Talents and skills are a subconscious memory, also known as **procedural** or **implicit memory** and often are excluded from amnesia, brainwashing or other memory  damaging events. Memories of specific events are **episodic** or **explicit memories**. Each is stored in a different area of the brain.

So, Sherlock forgetting an episodic memory like events with his sister would not remove procedural memories like playing the violin.

Comment: It seemed like Sherlock was suppressing any memories that involved his sister. If that was the case, then wouldn't he also suppress the memory of being taught how to play the violin by his sister? So even if he retained the skills involved in playing, he wouldn't know he had them.

Comment: @oliver no,  that's the point. Skills are not the same as personal memories. His changing of one doesn't affect the other. Any example of ante grade amnesia shows this. They don't remember learning the skill or language, but still retain the skill.

Comment: The [Wikipedia article on amnesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amnesia#Types) addresses this under Childhood Amnesia. They explicitly mention how playing an instrument is different from interacting with a person.

Comment: @cde - Yes, he retains the skill, but the point is, he doesn't know he has. E.g. I don't have any memories of learning how to play the violin, so if I suddenly discover that I can, I would certainly wonder when and how I learned it. Sherlock does not have Amnesia, he is not aware that he has blocked memories.

Answer (score 3):

From your question you quote "Mycroft told me you’d rewritten your memories" so the memories aren't just blocked, but actually changed. You've already given the example of how a person became a dog. So presumably he could have rewritten his memories of learning to play violin so that somebody else taught him or that he taught himself.